# jQuery how to match two text strings without changing either?

Tags: jquery, text, filter, hover, equivalent

Another newbie question...

The script (below) compares selected text in one div with some target text in another, then applies a style to the second div's parent. I need to change the script to be less literal---not "if A is selected, look for A"; but rather, "if Apples is selected, look for A."

So, how do you get jQuery to recognize two different text strings as being the same thing? I tried "var A = 'Apples', B = 'Bravo' [etc] ;", but then the class is added to .embox when I hover over any #menutable div.

The HTML:

```
    <div id="maintable">
     <div class="embox">
      content
      <div class="options">A,B,C</div>
     </div>
     <div class="embox">
      content
      <div class="options">B,F</div>
     </div>
     <!-- and about a hundred more just like these -->
    </div>

    <div id="menutable">
     <div class="optionA">Apples</div>
     <div class="optionB">Bravo</div>
     <div class="optionC">Comp</div>
     <div class="optionF">Ferengi</div>
    </div>
```

Current script (doesn't work):

```
$('#menutable div').hover(function() {
    var that = this, A = "Apples", B = "Bravo", C = "Comp", F = "Ferengi";
    $('#maintable .options').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().indexOf($(that).text()) === -1;
    }).closest(".embox").addClass("bgtransp");
},
function() {
    $(".embox").removeClass("bgtransp");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use jQuery's [inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method to see if the value is within an array of values that you define.

Example:

```
$.inArray($(this).html(), ['Apples', 'A', 'Orange']);
```

In your code, check to see if the function returns something greater than -1. More info can be found in the jQuery docs linked above.

Comment: The parameters are just an example, you should change them to fit your needs.

Comment: Since I can see how this will work, I've accepted the answer. For the record, however, I haven't tested it. I've found a way to make the literal match work in context. But down the road, when I'm a bit more comfortable with jQuery, I expect inArray() will be very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use data attributes

**HTML**

```
div id="menutable">
 <div class="option" data-letter="A">Apples</div>
 <div class="option" data-letter="B">Bravo</div>
 <div class="option" data-letter="C">Comp</div>
 <div class="option" data-letter="D">Ferengi</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#menutable div').hover(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#maintable .options').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().indexOf($(that).data('letter')) === -1;
        //seems to be !== -1 
    }).closest(".embox").addClass("bgtransp");
},
function() {
    $(".embox").removeClass("bgtransp");
});
```

Besides, You can get first letter from string useing `stringname[0]`

Comment: Since some of my clients are likely still on old browsers, I need to steer clear of HTML5. I think there's a way to adapt your suggestion by using the jQuery data() method, but the two things together are a bit over my head.

Comment: @Diorist: I think it should work in old browsers too. It will incorrect attribute for this browsers and they will be ignore it

Comment: also you can set data by JS and you HTMLcode will be clean in fact

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use HTML5 data-*, you can use

```
var myArray = ['Apples', 'A', 'Orange'];
var i=0;
$("#menutable > .option").each(
   function(){
     $(this).data("myOption",myArray[i]);
     i++;
});
```

and you can get the data using

```
$('#menutable > .option').click(function() {
   var myOption = $(this).data("myOption");
}
```

**note: its more web standard to set the id like `menu-table` instead of `menutable` :)**

Comment: Thanks for the ID naming advice and for your suggestion. Along with S.K.'s suggestion, it helps to demystify arrays.